# Upload file to an input area using FileApi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using **Capybara** + **RSpec** and the **capybara_webkit** as driver. And a JS uploader with FileApi.
I'm trying to upload three images here:

```
<input type="file" name="image" multiple="" accept="image/*">
```

When I click on the "Select photos" button (on the browser), it opens the typical window where I can select 3 files **from my computer**.

I'd like to know how to reproduce it on capybara, as when the photos selector opens, I don't have the control on it. I tried to add the pictures to my tests folder and tried:

```
attach_file('image', File.absolute_path('../pictures/photo1.JPG'))
```

but with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. My input area has opacity set to `0`, so that''s why i wasn't able to attach the files.
So i need to set its opacity to 1:

```
page.execute_script("$('input[name=file]').css('opacity','1')")
```