# Can't set input value of knockout js app via Selenium driver

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, knockout.js, capybara

I uses Selenium driver and Capybara for interact with external site, which coded on **Knockout JS**.

**The task is to set input value**. Yeah, so simple. Here is HTML of this stupid input:

```html
<input data-bind="value: $root.data.location.user_address,
                  valueUpdate: 'input', 
                  css: {'arenda-input_error': $root.validator.fieldsErrors['location.user_address']().length || $root.data.location.noResults()},
                  event: {keyup: function (data, event) {$root.data.location.onKeyUp(event); return true;},
                  blur: function () {$root.data.location.onBlur(); return true;}}" 
       placeholder="Минск, проспект Дзержинского, 5" 
       class="arenda-input arenda-input_full-width new-sub__input arenda-input_error"
       type="text">
```

What I already tried?

```
find('.new-sub__location-input').set 'My value'
```

**nothing happened**

```
page.execute_script %Q{$('.new-sub__location-input').val('My value').trigger('change')}
```

**nothing happened**

```
find('.new-sub__location-input').native.send_keys 'My value'
```

**same thing**

What's going on? How to set value for this input?

Comment: Have you tried giving the input an id, rather than finding it by css?

Comment: It hasn't an ID. It's an external site, I haven't access to their source code of course.

Comment: Have you tried the blur event? Without knowing the binding that's being used it could be a lot of different events which trigger the change: the standars are on the parameters section of http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html But that's if the ko binding is a value binding. It would be helpful to inspect the HTML and tell what binding it's being used, i.e. the value of the data-bind attribute. Can you show it?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957287/upload-file-to-an-input-area-using-fileapi/33961275#33961275 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269223/uploading-file-by-label-tag-in-capybara/34286615#34286615

Comment: The css class you're using in all your attempts doesn't actually match what you show in the html

Comment: @fabersky how it's relate to my question? I have no any probs with visibility.

Comment: @JotaBe I'm not flexible in Knockout, but as I can see in HTML it's ```valueUpdate: 'input'```

Comment: try finding element as follow: `find(:css, 'input[class*=new-sub__location-input]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your attempts shown appear to be using a different css class than the input element you show.  If the html you have with the question is correct then the following should work

```
find(:css, '.new-sub__input').set('My value')
```

or since fill_in can work with the placeholder attribute

```
fill_in("Минск, проспект Дзержинского, 5", with: 'My value')
```

Comment: Right, seems it was changed after first load.